# table sorter with nested tables issue?

Tags: javascript, tablesorter

In the mentioned fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/P2DsY/ headers are Make Model.
These two are having child data.instead of sorting all the child and parent,i need to sort the only parent headers i want sort against make then
1)ouptut :

```
**Make     Model**
Honda   Accord
Honda 2-Door    Honda Red
Honda 4-Door    Honda Blue
Toyota  Camry
Toyota 2-Door   Toyota Yellow
Toyota 4-Door   Toyota Green
```

if again sort with make need to display the output as below
2)output :

```
    **Make   Model**   
    Toyota  Camry
    Toyota 2-Door   Toyota Yellow
    Toyota 4-Door   Toyota Green
    Honda   Accord
    Honda 2-Door    Honda Red
    Honda 4-Door    Honda Blue
```

Please tell me how to sort the table like that instead of sorting all tables need to sort based on parent content ..

Answer (score 2):

The problem in the demo is that "expand-child" is not the default class name for child rows.

I've [updated the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/P2DsY/197/) with the following script:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{ 
    $("table").tablesorter({
        theme: 'blue',
        cssChildRow: 'expand-child',
        // the following isn't necessary, but I left it there...
        selectorHeaders: '> thead > tr > th'
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Your demo is spot on. All is well here. Thanks for the answer.